# Jquery ajax parse error

Tags: jquery, json

My server side will reply with json look like  `{} && {"id":2....}`  . i use jquery.ajax to GET the response. but i keep getting "error parseerror" , how to parse data like this using jquery.ajax?

Comment: can you post the complete JSON string so that we can verify the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code that is giving you the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is **not** valid jSon.........

Answer (score 1):

You should return only one json object at a time.  If you need to return more than one data model, then build an array or set of objects in the json object.

```
{itemOne:{}, itemTwo:{}, arrayOfSomething:[]}
```